# eclipselink does not apply persistence-unit-defaults to sequence

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm playing around with JPA, specifically eclipselink 4.0.1, and want to use a specific schema in a postgres database. To do so, I've added an orm.xml file with

```
   <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>mySchema</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>
```

which does seem to work for all "normal" tables, but not for the SEQUENCE. When I use `eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode` to look at the generated ddl file, it comes out as something like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE mySchema.tableA...
  CREATE TABLE mySchema.tableB...
  ALTER TABLE mySchema.tableA...
  ALTER TABLE mySchema.tableB...
  ...
  CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(38), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))
  INSERT INTO SEQUENCE(SEQ_NAME, SEQ_COUNT) values ('SEQ_GEN', 0)
```

The SEQUENCE table does not have the mySchema specification for some reason. Am I missing a small piece of configuration somewhere? Any place else I could look or additional information I should provide?

**Workaround**

Everything works if I create the SEQUENCE table "manually". To do so, I've added the createSequenceTableIfNotExists-method below as a workaround for now:

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;

public enum PersistenceTool {
    DEFAULT;
    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    PersistenceTool() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(name().toLowerCase());
        createSequenceTableIfNotExists("mySchema");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(entityManagerFactory::close));
    }

//  ...

    EntityManager getNewEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    private void createSequenceTableIfNotExists(String schema) {
        final var entityManager = getNewEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + schema + ".SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(38), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME));" +
                 "INSERT INTO " + schema + ".SEQUENCE(SEQ_NAME, SEQ_COUNT) values ('SEQ_GEN', 0) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;")
            .executeUpdate();
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Note that creating the EntityManagerFactory does produce a warning that no SEQUENCE table exists yet, but that does not cause any lasting problems.

Comment: Are you sure your orm.xml file is being picked up? Seems similar but very opposite to the problem in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445466 where the schema was used twice, and there should be a unit test in the code to verify this works. Is this problem only with DDL generation of the table? (ie if you manually create the mySchema.SEQUENCE table and first entry, does the code run?)

Comment: Why would the ddl contain _mySchema_.tableA etc. if it did not pick up on the orm-file? And yes, I do get a warning at startup that the SEQUENCE table is missing. As a workaround, I have a piece of code that explicitly creates the sequence table via EntityManager#createNativeQuery (if missing). After doing that, I can work with entities as expected.

Comment: I'm not clear on your workaround or your answer- are you saying that the issue IS only with DDL? Are you creating the 'mySchema.SEQUENCE' table and the app is working after?

Comment: As for why it would pick up 'mySchema' on your tables - there are many ways to set the schema in EclipseLink outside of the orm.xml. For all I know, you could have customizer set that runs across all descriptors (entities) and sets the schema to 'mySchema', and just have missed the sequence table (which doesn't have a descriptor). Or a separate ORM file somewhere that IS picked up that defines each entity and sets their schema. File a bug if you can reproduce this simply and go through paid support if you want instead (Oracle and IBM both support this I believe)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I've edited the current workaround into the question; hopefully this clears things up. As the orm-file and my PersistenceTool class are the only two places (as per IntelliJs full text search) containing "mySchema", I don't think eclipselink could have picked that up from anywhere else. Maybe I'll try to reproduce in an even smaller project to investigate a bit further and/or file a bug-report. But as I'm just playing around in a small spare-time application, its not a super pressing issue.

Comment: So it is just a DDL issue. You can create the DDL scripts and manually edit them as required, or a more production level security conscious approach might be to create the scripts without the schema and then run them separately as a particular user with table creation privileges with the default schema set to 'mySchema'. Running DDL statements as the same runtime user running your application is usually viewed as a security hole, so I usually create a separate persistence unit just to create/run scripts with a different admin level datasource in development environments.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up these concerns! They sounds very reasonable and I'll certainly consider them, should that program ever leave the state where the database structure changes (relatively) often and it's just me using it.